# PHP Decryption from Node.js Encryption

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I used the following code I found online to do some basic encryption/decryption. It works as expected but I have someone who's stuck on decrypting it in PHP.

I'm trying to do it myself but my PHP is a bit rusty having not used it for a few years now.

```
// Checking the crypto module
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

// Encrypting text
function encrypt(text) {
   let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', Buffer.from(key), iv);
   let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
   encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
   return { iv: iv.toString('hex'), encryptedData: encrypted.toString('hex') };
}

// Decrypting text
function decrypt(text) {
   let iv = Buffer.from(text.iv, 'hex');
   let encryptedText = Buffer.from(text.encryptedData, 'hex');
   let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', Buffer.from(key), iv);
   let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
   decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
   return decrypted.toString();
}
```

I thought it should look something like this but when testing, I keep getting gibberish output.

```
openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedData), "aes-256-ctr", base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, hex2bin($iv));
```